# What the white box testers create test cases against?

Tags: testing, test-coverage

I'm wondering, what are the white box testers using to create test cases? The actual code? Some kind of diagrams?

I mean, if I am given a task to create test cases for complete branch coverage, is it possible they give me a code?

Because I saw something like that:

```
Reader r=null;
if(condition)
{
  r=new Reader();
}
r.toString();
```

There is an obvious bug as the last statement should be in the body of the If statement. It will be easily exposed by false-decision test case of the condition.

But is it not more like unit tests? What is then the white box testers goal of testing?

Wikipedia article on [white-box testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing) states:

> The tester chooses inputs to exercise paths through the code and determine the appropriate outputs.

I understand this as you choose inputs to reach the coverage and reveal possible bugs. But isn't it simple unit testing done by developers?

Comment: did you check respective Wikipedia article: **[White-box testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing)**?

Comment: gnat, yes I did. It is more about coverage. It does not say anyting about what to test against.

Comment: @user1134916 You just answered your own question, coverage IS what you test against.  Methods, Functions, decision points, classes, you need to find what's important in the code, since you know what it does and where it's supposed to do it, go from there.

Comment: Jeff Langemeier: no that would not make sense...coverage is a goal. You can test against code or diagrams (flowcharts?)..that is all I can think of

Comment: @user1134916 hm per my reading of the article, it rather clearly states testing is done against _inputs_, doesn't it? "The **tester chooses inputs** to exercise paths through the code and determine the appropriate outputs. "

Comment: Surely you choose inputs to reach the coverage and reveal possible bugs. But..isnt it simple unit testing done by developers?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, white box testing is akin to unit tests created by developers.

However, see the following for a discussion:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892963/does-unit-testing-falls-under-white-box-or-black-box-testing

If they are asking you to white-box test something then you will need to read the code to come up with the tests.